# malloc-ing a structure in C that has structures as elements?

Tags: c

Say I have

```
struct node {
  struct example *left;
  struct example *right;
  int whatever;
};

struct example { 
  struct example *foo;
  struct example *bar;
}
```

Now when I do

```
struct node *example_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

to initialize my node structure, what does this malloc actually do? I know it's supposed to allocate memory so that example_node can point to an address somewhere that contains enough bytes for a whole struct node.... but what is opened up?

Is it

a) enough space for a blank template of  a structure is initiated

b) are the two structures inside of struct node also initiated? So can I start doing stuff like example_node->left->foo?

c) Is the struct example *foo for left and right also initiated?

I'm just confused on what I have access to, what I need to free, etc.

Comment: `malloc` gets that number of bytes of uninitialized memory; nothing more

Comment: Also your title does not match the code:  your struct has *pointers* as elements, and an int, not structures

Comment: Sorry I meant to say structure pointers. And so if malloc gets the number of bytes of uninitialized memory, that means that only a pointer to the struct node (example_node) gets "opened" right? But I'm confused on the meaning of that. Does that mean that as far as C knows, struct node (example_node) could have a million arrays inside it or just a char, or 4 strings, whatever, it's just a pointer? Then how come I was able to write example_node->left = NULL; right away instead of having to allocate memory for left? I could also do example_node->right = NULL;

Comment: I suggest avoiding phrase like "allocate memory for left", it is not clear whether you refer to storage of `left`, or storage that `left` will point to. Maybe you are confused about the distinction between those two things in your mind too.  You can do `x->left = NULL;` for the same reason you can do `x->whatever = 0;`

Comment: Does NULL and 0 not require any memory?

Comment: a struct node is a left, a right, and a whatever. If you have a struct node, then you have a left, a right and a whatever. If you allocate a struct node, then you allocated a left, a right and a whatever. But left is just a pointer and some people might think that when you say "allocated a left" it means a struct example was allocated., which it was not.

Comment: They require memory, they are stored in the memory you allocated

Comment: Every `malloc` needs a `free` just like every opening parenthesis needs a closing one. Just like `([{}])` is correct and `([{)]}` is wrong, you should free memory in opposite order of the allocation.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this

- `sizeof(struct node)` gives the size of the `node` structure
- `malloc( N )` allocates N bytes from memory

Thus `malloc(sizeof(struct node))` allocates at least the number of bytes needed to store a `struct node`.

Inside the structure `node`

```
struct example *left;
struct example *right;
int whatever;
```

these are two *pointers* to the structure `example` and an integer.

Thus the allocated memory space is big enough to contain these 2 pointers, and an `int`. Not the whole `example` structures, only pointers.

In order to complete the allocation, you probably want to allocate the two internal structures as well, like

```
struct node *example_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

example_node->left  = malloc(sizeof(struct example));
example_node->right = malloc(sizeof(struct example));
```

---

You free these allocations in reverse order,

1. start to free `left` and `right`
2. *Then* free the `node` structure

As soon as you free something, it's no longer available. That *might* work, but this is undefined behavior.

So if you free first the `node`, you cannot reliably reach the `left` and `right` members which are dependent on `node` (being inside).

```
free (example_node->left);
free (example_node->right);

free (example_node);
```

Comment: Hmmm... I'm starting to understand a bit, so when I initialize "example_node", I wasn't being specific at all, I was just going "Ok open up enough memory to store enough space for 2 pointers and an int", not "open up enough memory for a STRUCT NODE, that includes TWO OTHER STRUCTURES WHICH INCLUDE OTHER STRUCTURES and an integer"

Comment: There is no recursive allocation. The malloc you did allocates the `node` structure only. *Then* you have to allocate the internal members separately. Edited.

Comment: Ok cool, and when I do free(example_node), will I also have to do free(example_node->left); and free(example_node->right);

Comment: Oh right that's what I meant. That confuses me though, how come when I allocate memory, all I have to do is struct node *example_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));, but when I have to free memory, I have to free everything separately? And once I initialize example_node->left->foo, I would have to free foo separately as well?

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: @ming A `struct node` IS two pointers and an int. Those are the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will allocate enough memory to store two pointers and one integer. It will not allocate memory for the two pointers to point at.

> Then how come I was able to write example_node->left = NULL; right away instead of having to allocate memory for left?

This would change the pointer, by writing `NULL` to the memory allocated to the pointer, just like `example_node->whatever = 0` would write `0` to the memory allocated to the integer. It does not do anything with any memory outside the node struct itself. However, if you were to say `example_node->left->foo = NULL`, you would be doing a Bad Thing (tm).

---

**EDIT**: I think you still have issues about memory of pointer and memory under pointer. Let's try an analogy. Imagine you live in an apartment building, where you can rent storage space in the basement. Imagine also that every apartment comes pre-furnished, part of which is a key rack next to the entrance. The key rack has a hook with a label "Storage Key".

If you have rented a storage room, you can put its key on the appropriate rack hook. If you have no storage room, then the hook is empty. Whether or not you have a storage room, you have allocated space for a storage room *key* (the rack hook), that is separate from the storage room itself. The key hook exists independently of the storage space.

Trying to open a storage room using no key is illegal.

Trying to open a stranger's storage room with a key you happened to find the building garage is illegal.

You can only open a room you *own*.

---

`node` is your apartment: if you have allocated `node` (if you have the apartment) you have space for the pointer `left` (you have the storage room key rack hook). `node->left` has memory allocated for it as part of `node` allocation (you get the storage key hook whether you rent storage or not).

You can assign `NULL` to `left` (putting nothing on the hook), or you can assign a pointer value (putting a key on the hook).

If `left` is `NULL`, you *can't* do `example_node->left->foo = ...` because a null pointer explicitly says it is not pointing to any allocated memory (can't open any storage rooms without a key).

You *can* do `example_node->left = 0xdeadbeef` (put someone else's storage room key on your hook), but you *can't* then `example_node->left->foo = ...` because the space at `0xdeadbeef` is likely not yours to tamper with (using someone else's storage room).

You *can* do `example_node->left = malloc(...)` (rent a storage room and place its key on the storage room hook), and after that you *can* do `example_node->left->foo = ...` (because you own the room and the key, and you can put in new stuff there if you want to).

Comment: So then.. example_node-left->NULL was initialized along with example_node then? If I'm allowed to write NULL "to the memory allocated to the pointer"? Then if that was initialized along with example_node, how come example_node->left->foo was not initialized along with example_node->left

Comment: `NULL` is just a pointer value, `0x00000000`. It marks an invalid pointer, or pointer with no data; it does not have any memory associated with it at the target of the pointer. (You can't write to `0x00000000`). You have memory of the pointer itself to do with as you please (to write `0x00000000` or to write e.g. `0xdeadbeef` into it); but unless the memory at that address is properly allocated to you (e.g. `malloc` returned `0xdeadbeef`) it is illegal to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're in an x64 environment with packing and without alignment, then `sizeof( struct node ) == 20` because `8 + 8 + 4 == 20`:

```
sizeof( struct example* ) == 8        // Remember this struct member is a pointer, not a value
sizeof( struct example* ) == 8        // Ditto
sizeof( int             ) == 4        // `int` is usually 4 bytes
```

> what does this malloc actually do? I know it's supposed to allocate memory so that example_node can point to an address somewhere that contains enough bytes for a whole struct node

This is correct.

In a typical desktop operating system's userland, your code will runs in a process' memory space. Memory (often) comes in large chunks called "pages" provided by the operating system and the C runtime's `malloc` will request these pages and then manage the allocation of data *within* these pages.

In a desktop OS environment, `malloc( 20 )` does something like this:

- Do we have enough space in an available page for a contiguous 20 bytes?

  - Yes? Then use our internal memory map to find a contiguous 20 byte area and return the address of the first byte of that area.
  - No? Then request a new page from the operating system, add it to our internal memory map, and return the address of an area in that new page

    - If the new page request failed, then return `NULL`.

> a) Is it enough space for a blank template of a structure is initiated

Short answer: yes - because you did `malloc( sizeof( struct node ) )`, *however* `malloc` can fail (in which case it returns `NULL` (`0`) and it's important that you check this after every allocation. This can happen due to running out of memory, excessive fragmentation, etc.

```
struct node *example_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
if( !example_node ) {
    puts( "Allocation failed. Exiting." );
    exit( 1 );
}
```

> b) are the two structures inside of struct node also initiated? So can I start doing stuff like example_node->left->foo?

No. Those members are pointers. You need to initialize them yourself. You can initialize them by making further `malloc` calls or by assigning them to other existant `struct node` objects in memory.

> c) Is the struct example *foo for left and right also initiated?

No. Se my above answer.

Your `struct node` and `struct example` cases can be populated recursively indefinitely - how far deep you go depends on you.

To create a simple binary tree that's 3 nodes deep:

```
struct node* allocateNode() {
    struct node* newNode = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    if( !newNode ) exit( 1 ); // fast-fail
    newNode.left  = NULL; // zero-out the pointer members because `malloc` does not zero out memory for you!
    newNode.right = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

void initializeNode( struct node* parent ) {

    parent.left  = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    parent.right = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
}

void createTree( struct node* parent, int depth ) {

    if( depth <= 0 ) return NULL;

    parent.left  = allocateNode();

    createTree( parent.left, depth - 1 );

    parent.right = allocateNode();

    createTree( parent.right, depth - 1 );
}

void destroyTree( struct node* node ) {

    if( node == NULL ) return;

    destroyTree( node.left );
    destroyTree( node.right );

    free( node );
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {

    struct node* root = allocateNode();

    createTree( root, 3 );

    // (do stuff here)

    destroyTree( root );

    return 0;
}
```

I note that you could do it more efficiently by using `calloc` and allocating all nodes at once:

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {

    const size_t n = 7; // a tree 3 layers deep has 7 nodes: 1, 2L, 2R, 3LL, 3LR, 3RL, 3RR
    struct node[] allNodes = calloc( n, sizeof(struct node) ); 
    if( !allNodes ) exit( 1 );

    // Binary heap array representation algorithm:
    size_t lastParent = 3;
    for( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {

        if( i < lastParent ) {
            allNodes[i].left  = allNodes[ ( 2 * i ) + 1 ];
            allNodes[i].right = allNodes[ ( 2 * i ) + 2 ];
        }
        else {
            allNodes[i].left  = NULL;
            allNodes[i].right = NULL;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

### IMPORTANT NOTE!!!!!!11111!

Never forget to call `free` for every successful `malloc` or `calloc` call! Otherwise you will leak memory!

Comment: So I commented this above, but how come then I'm allowed to do stuff like example_node->left = NULL, and example_node->whatever = 0; ??

and when I free, say I initialize example_node->left, do I have to say free(example_node->left); 
free(example_node); ????

Comment: And you said I can go really deep, so I have to probably write a loop to free all the ones I allocated right?

Comment: You're "allowed" to do anything in C, even if it doesn't make any sense - it just means your program will crash (if you're lucky) or you'll corrupt your process memory ("undefined behaviour").

Comment: @ming It's common to use recursion instead of loops when processing trees. Look at the `destroyTree` function I provided.

Comment: Hmm okay thanks. And when I do sizeof(example), I'm getting 24, not 20...

Comment: " `int` is usually 4 bytes " - in different architectures it can be 8 (in some modern computers) or 2 (in some not so modern ones). Thus, for your system, it is `8 + 8 + 8`

Comment: @ming Yes. 24 is normal. The value depends on your computer. I gave an value of 20 as an example only.

Comment: @Amadan Yes, that's why I said "**usually 4 bytes**" but it can be others too.

Comment: @Dai: I was just drawing attention to what you wrote for the OP; no critique of your text implied.